# How do I export an XCode app so I can publish it on my website, not in the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac, xcode, websites

How do I export an XCode app so I can publish it on my website, not in the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 3):

You have to export you application as a `.app` bundle and then it's the `.app` bundle that you sell or give away on your own web site to pass the application along. From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812650/how-do-you-export-your-finished-application-from-xcode):

In XCode 4, applications are exported from the "Organizer" and you build a `.app` bundle for redistribution by building an archive of the application:

- On the menu go to `Product` -> `Archive`
- Once you're in the `Organizer - Archives` screen click `Distribute` button if you're using XCode 4.3.3 or higher, click the `Share` button for releases before 4.3.3
- Then choose the format you want to export.